# Mobile view of user profile pages b0rken / kaput / pining for the fjords

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, mobile-web

I get the *Oops! Something Bad Happened!* ASPX 500 error page whenever I try and view *any* user profile using the mobile web view. This happens on any of the Stack Exchange sites:

[image: error page on Stack Overflow]
[image: error page on Meta Stack Exchange]

Clicking on a different link (say, the homepage), then switching back to the full site view makes it possible view profile pages, but that's not much of an option on an iPhone, of course.

To reproduce, go to a user profile, and click on the *mobile view* link in the footer. To get back, click on *Users* or *Tags* and then on the *full site* link in the footer. Or use a mobile device browser, which is served the mobile view by default.

Site revision: 2015.2.13.2296 (Meta 2015.2.13.3073)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for letting us know. Should be fixed now.

I'm ... not entirely sure what went wrong here. I mean, I know *what*, but I don't know *why*. I'm fixing the actual exception, and will ping the devs working on user profile improvements to have them look over the mobile views to make sure everything's kosher going forward.

P.S. Look on the bright side: if the user profile hadn't been nailed to the perch, it'd be pushing up the daisies!

Comment: And the profiles are back. Thanks!